# android: check if the app updated or new user

Tags: android

I want to update an app. but I want to check either this user new or old( had ever been install my app?) I thought I can check the **sharedpreferences**. but maybe the user cleared the data.
any other ideas?

**Regards**

Comment: Although you must suppose that user is new if prefs are clear. But if you don't want that then you can save a file on sd card which won't get deleted after clearing data. And then you can just check if that files exists or not.

Comment: Do your users a favor and **don't** save a file on the sd card which won't be deleted after clearing data. There's enough junk on my SD card from random apps already.

Comment: I think of a new one. I can check the first Installed data. but its not supported on api 8

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to see if a user has previously installed your application and are worried about the user possibly altering the state of your phone, you can contact a separate database to retrieve which device ID has previously installed the application.

Upon first use of your application, you can save the device ID.

To determine the unique device ID, you can look at

[Is there a unique Android device ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)

Comment: I don't like to collect any information of my users. but it's still nice ;)